# Can we implement Spring batch application without Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Can we implement Spring batch application without Spring Boot  ?

Comment: Yes sure. But why don't you want to use Spring Boot?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli : We have a requirement to run the spring batch in the Jboss application server .

Comment: Yes you can use Spring Batch without Spring Boot. Spring Batch existed years before Spring Boot came out. With this requirement of running your jobs in an application server, how are you going to launch your jobs? Will all your jobs run on the same JVM running your application server? How would you scale such architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an executable JAR you can also deploy a Spring Boot application as a WAR to JBoss.

The SpringBootApplication class will look a bit different:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And you have to use

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Please find more information in the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file